# What does the asterisk (*) mean in lsof output?

Tags: lsof, syntax

I set my TCP server to localhost `127.0.0.1`, but instead of seeing `127.0.0.1` in the host portion of the `lsof` output, I see an asterisk.

After running `lsof -i`...

```
my_process 66666 root 5u IPv4 0xffff...c0 0t0 TCP *:5001 (LISTEN)
```

What does this asterisk mean?  Is my socket bound to localhost, does it not have an address or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that limiting your server to localhost was not successful (maybe you have to restart is?) because it is listening on all interfaces, accepting all destination IP addresses.