# lsof output file descriptor with asterisk not documented

Tags: linux, lsof, syntax

When I run `lsof` I see the output

```
java      1752736                               user 9995u     sock                0,8       0t0 1432559505 protocol: TCPv6
java      1752736                               user *527u     sock                0,8       0t0 1444900878 protocol: TCPv6
```

What does the `*` in front of the file descriptor indicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the asterisk (\*) mean in lsof output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439536/what-does-the-asterisk-mean-in-lsof-output)

Comment: @eyoung100 that question seems to address the presence of an asterisk in the `NAME` field of lsof's output, but this question is asking about an asterisk in the `FD` (file descriptor) field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer versions of the man page explain it (addressing [this issue](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/pull/261)). Checking out [its roff source code](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/blob/e30113e5eb151a83d7a4d0935f58b6b542ed31eb/Lsof.8#L2600) (emphasize mine):

> The FD column contents constitutes a single field for parsing in
> post-processing scripts. ***FD numbers larger than 9999 are abbreviated
> to a `*` followed by the last three digits***. E.g., 10001 appears as
> `*001`

Comment: It seems it also affects the *output for other programs* with `-F` as in `bash -c 'ulimit -n 20000; exec 12345> /dev/null; lsof -w -F fd -ap "$$" /dev/null; exit'` which I would consider a bug.

Comment: I've raised it at https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof/issues/311. We'll see what the maintainers say.